# Protoplasm Date Picker : Issue with different datetime format

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, datepicker

I am working an application having I18N support. In this application, based on user's locale user is prompted enters date time in locale specific format along with other details in a form. We have used [protoplasm date time picker](http://jongsma.org/software/protoplasm/control/datepicker?page=datepicker) to select date time.

Right now we are facing an issue with specific datetime format where the plugin shows wrong hours. Here is the html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script language="javascript" src="protoplasm.js"></script>
        <script language="javascript">
            // transform() calls can be chained together
            Protoplasm.use('datepicker')
                .transform('input.datepicker', {timePicker:true, use24hrs:false, dateTimeFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm a'} )
                .transform('input.datetimepicker')
                ;
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="text" name="date" class="datepicker" />
    </body>
</html>
```

When user click on PM box on the plugin it shows 16-04-2012 **22:59 PM** instead of 16-04-2012 **10:59 PM**. However if he click on AM box it works.

Has anyone faced such issues?

Please help me to resolve this problem.

Thanks, Amit Patel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced `HH` with `hh` in `dateTimeFormat` and it worked.