# Issue intergrating Protoplasm date picker in my web page,

Tags: datepicker, jscript

I needed a date and time picker and Protoplasm (http://jongsma.org/software/protoplasm/control/datepicker) had exactly what I need but I have been unable to get it to work. Unfortunately I am unable to get access to their API documentation (Restricted).

I added it to my web page but it only displayed a normal input field. After many attempts to fix it I grabbed the source of their demo page but could not get it to work.

I then cut it down to the code below. I have checked and double checked the includes exist in the same dir as the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
     <title>Protoplasm</title>
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="protoplasm.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.7.0.0/prototype.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/scriptaculous/1.8.3/scriptaculous.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="protoplasm.js"></script>
     <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
         Protoplasm.use('datepicker') .transform('.datetimepicker', { timePicker: true })
     </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h2>Protoplasm</h2>
        <form onsubmit="return false;">
            <div style="float:left; width:250px;">Date and time:</div>
            <input class="datetimepicker"/>
            <br />
        </form>
    <div>   
</body>
</html>
```

I googled the problem and found two answers on "stackoverflow" but it did not help.

[Protoplasm Date Picker : Issue with different datetime format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10509949/protoplasm-date-picker-issue-with-different-datetime-format)

The code on the above page did not work for me either. I am at a loss for what to check next. I would appreciate it if someone would make a suggestion as to what I should check next.

Answer (score 0):

I put this and it runs okay:

```
var D = {locale: 'es_AR', timePicker: true, use24hrs: true,
         dateTimeFormat: 'dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm'};
Protoplasm.use('datepicker').transform('input.datepicker', D );
```

The problem I have is that not how to capture the event when a date is selected. I want to work for a date without time (without timepicker), I used the option `'onSelect'` but it does not work, you know how to do it?